# How to remove chemical stain from granite composite?

Tags: cleaning, sink, kitchen-sink, stain, stain-removal

I've left a sponge soaked in alkaline anti grease cleaner on a granite composite sink AND on worktop that is covered in plastic (?) laminate, and now there are two white burn marks.
Is there any way to remove or mask them?[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. I'm guessing not, but let's see what our pros say. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know you'll know the details of contributing here.

Comment: You should probably post what cleaner or at least the solvent so we know what we are working with. Also, you might want to book a hotel room if you're married

Comment: Do you know the sealer that was used on the granite? I have had to repolish granite in the past when the sealer was etched off very similar to yours. You may be able to buff it out and reseal. The wood grain may be a tougher case if the surface was damaged restoring the shine may help but may not remove the clouded look.